# show hidden sheets with macro - qlikview

Tags: macros, qlikview

Can I show all hidden sheets or get hidden sheet with macro?

ex:

```
ActiveDocument.GetSheet("Età").GetProperties.Show.Always = true
```

thx!

Answer (score 1):

I would have a variable in the conditional show of the sheet; vHide = 0. If it's 0 then it is visible and you can use 1 for when it should be hidden.

Then you can set the variable with the macro:

```
Sub ShowSheets
    set Hide = ActiveDocument.Variables("vHide")
    Hide.SetContent 0, true
End Sub
```

This can of course be done without the macro by using a set variable action instead.